# How can safely assign an incrementing ID to a subset of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have an `Order` object which can be in an unpaid or paid state. When an order is paid, I want to set an `order_number` which should be an incrementing number.

Sounds easy enough, but I'm worried about collisions. I can imagine one order having an `order_number` stored in memory, about to save and then another order saves itself, using that number, now the one in memory should be recalculated, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a database table that just contains an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key.  When you need to to get a new order_number just do an insert into this table and get the the value of the primary key for the created row.

Comment: This seems a little silly but I haven't heard anything better. In my case, I've decided it actually makes sense to attach another model to Orders when they have been paid. I'll be able to use the ID of that model.

Comment: There was an interesting blog post over at the MySQL Performannce Blog related to this topic.  Basically they benchmarked the approach I described against another approach and found this one scales much better (a good quick read if your interested): http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/04/sharing-an-auto_increment-value-across-multiple-mysql-tables/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of approaches. Essentially you need a lock to ensure that each request to the counter always return a different value.

Memcache, Redis and some key-value stores have this kind of counter feature. eg, each time you want to get a new `order_number`, just call the [`incr`](http://redis.io/commands/incr) command of Redis, it will increment the counter and return the new value.

A more complex solution can be implemented via the trigger/stored procedure/sequence features of RMDBS(like mysql). For mysql, create a new table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key. When you want to get a new `order_number`, make an insert into this table and get `last_insert_id()`. If you want ACID, just wrap the procedure in a transaction.